# Testing controller's redirect in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a rspec test testing a controller action.

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # This redirect sends the user to SalesController#go_to_home
    redirect_to '/go_to_home'
  end

  def go_to_home
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

My controller test looks like

```
RSpec.describe SalesController, type: :controller do
  include PathsHelper

  describe 'POST create' do
    post :create

    expect(response).to redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

However, when I run the test it tells me that:

```
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/go_to_home>.
   Expected "http://test.host/" to be === "http://test.host/go_to_home".
```

`/go_to_home` will send the user to SalesController#go_to_home. How can I test that the response will eventually lead to the home page with the url `http://test.host/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller tests are effectively unit tests - you are testing the effect of calling a single action and what the expected behaviour of that action is.

The `create` action does return a response back with a status code of `302` and includes in the header a `Location` indicating the new URI, which in the case of calling create would be `Location: http://localhost/go_to_home`

This is as far as the controller test goes. It has emulated a call made from a browser to the create action and received the initial redirection.

In the real world of course the browser would then navigate to the given location and would then hit the `go_to_home` action but this is beyond the scope of controller tests ... this is in the domain of integration testing.

So, either,

1. Create an integration test to initially call the `create` action, follow the redirection and test that you end up at '/'.
2. Change the controller test to `expect(response).to redirect_to '/go_to_home'`
3. Change the `create` action to redirect directly to '/'

Answer (score 5):

Why are you expecting to be redirect to '/' in the specs? 
From the controller code you pasted you are going to be redirected to '/go_to_home' after hitting the create action

Try changing the specs to:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to '/go_to_home'
```

Edit:

Is this a real example or the code is just for sharing what you are trying to achieve? 
I don't think rspec will follow the redirect after going to '/go_to_home' and I think is fine.

If you are testing the create action it's ok to test that redirects to '/go_to_home' because that's what action is doing.
Then you can do another test for the other action `go_to_home` and expect that redirects to root.

Are you calling the action 'go_to_home' from somewhere else?

Comment: I will clarify my question. `/go_to_home` will send the user to SalesController#go_to_home.

Comment: No, I'm only calling go_to_home from SalesController#create. Understand I've simplified this example down so there's a lot of logic missing.